# How to save utils when creating a C library?

Tags: c

How should I go about saving a function that is used for other functions when creating my own C library?

For example, here is a function that is repeatedly called in other functions that I have created:

```
int strlen(char *s){
    int counter=0;
    for(int i=0; s[i] != '\0'; i++){
        counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

I am looking for a method to include this as a util but I am not quite sure how to go about saving then implementing it to separate .c functions I have created.

Comment: `strlen` is a function in the C standard library. You should most definitely not implement that yourself.

Comment: Sorry should have specified, the point of the library I created, was to create functions without calling the <string.h> library.

Comment: Trush Patel, Note the standard has `size_t strlen(const char *s)`, different in/out types than yours - result: potential different functionality.

Comment: When you create library (module) you should name functions with module name prefix, eg.: `json_strlen()`, `json_addNode()` ... `myLib_someFunction()`

Comment: @TrushPatel Right, Angew was saying that you should not avoid using the C standard library.

Comment: So are you asking how to call functions in one source file from another source file? It's not clear what you mean by "save".

Comment: @Sneftel I would, if it wasn't part of the assignment. Our assignment only allowed us to use <stdlib.h> and <stdio.h>

Comment: @Sneftel correct. I wanted to save this function and then call it in another source file.

Answer (score 1):

Create a private header file somewhere in your source tree, such as directly alongside your library's source files. Declare the utility function(s) in this header file. Then add a source file with its implementation, and make this source file part of your library's sources.

In effect, the only difference between a "client-visible" function and "internal-only" function in the library is whether you make the declaration header public or not.

Comment: You mean you don't build your release libraries from a .c file that includes all others and -DINTERNAL static /me ducks

Answer (score 0):

> How to save utils when creating a C library?

This is tricky when the util function is a same name replacement as a standard library as various other `.c` files may need the original standard function - especially for test code to compare functions.

---

Rename function and save in "TP.c"

```
// int strlen(char *s){
int TP_strlen(char *s){
```

Form header "TP.h"

```
int TP_strlen(char *s);
// and inline or define
inline int strlen(char *s) { return TP_strlen(s); }
```

Do **not** include both `"TP.h"` and `<string.h>`

---

Strongly recommend to use the *same* function signature as standard functions.

```
// int TP_strlen(char *s)
size_t TP_strlen(const char *s)
```